# Replace all x after first occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string: `/repos/facebook/react/native`.
I need to remove /repos/ and then all the slashes after the first one need to be dashes.

So for the above example this is the result: `faceboook/react-native`.

Other examples:
Start: `/repos/google/angular/cli`
End: `google/angular-cli`

Start: `/repos/aksonov/react/native/router/flux`
End: `aksonov/react-native-router-flux`

I have started with `.replace('/repos/', '')` then began to do a hacky split (by `/`)[0] + map. But I was wondering if there was an easier less-clustered way of doing it with regex? I'd imagine I'll have to remove the /repos/, so the question is just how to replace all of the slashes AFTER the first one.

Any ideas appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple, you can can do this:

```
function repl(str) {
   return str.replace('/repos/', '').replace(/\//g, '-').replace('-', '/')
}
```

Then call it as:

```
repl('/repos/google/angular/cli')
//=> "google/angular-cli"

repl('/repos/aksonov/react/native/router/flux')
//=> "aksonov/react-native-router-flux"
```

It does the job in 3 steps:

1. Replace `/repos/` by empty string
2. Replace all `/` by `-`
3. Replace first `-` by `/`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a javascript wizard, but what about this simple approach:

```
s = "/repos/aksonov/react/native/router/flux";
s = s.replace('/repos/', '');
bits = s.split('/');
final = bits[0]+'/'+bits.slice(1).join('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/\/repos\/(.*)\/(.*)/,"$1-$2");
```

Its working https://jsfiddle.net/p9mkkk2p/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
const data = ['/repos/aksonov/react/native/router/flux', '/repos/google/angular/cli', '/repos/facebook/react/native']

const reducePath = path => path.replace(/\/.*?\//,'').replace(/\//g, '-').replace(/-/, '/')

for (let path of data){
    console.log(`${path} -> ${reducePath(path)}`)
}
```